# I am having trouble getting a script to run with the proper directories and files

Tags: ruby, bash, directory, homebrew, filepath

I am attempting to install Homebrew using [this script](https://gist.github.com/skyl/36563a5be809e54dc139) from [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/619498/can-i-install-homebrew-without-sudo-privileges/881681#881681).

However, I am having trouble getting the directories on my machine to be setup correctly.

The closest I got was changing this:

```
YOUR_HOME = ''

HOMEBREW_PREFIX = "#{YOUR_HOME}/usr/local"
```

To this:

```
YOUR_HOME = ''

HOMEBREW_PREFIX = "usr/local"
```

The file was in and run from `Users/<User_name>`, but I got this output:

```
==> This script will install:
usr/local/bin/brew
usr/local/Library/...
usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
mkdir: usr: No such file or directory
Failed during: /bin/mkdir usr/local
```

My files at the moment are setup like this:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: try `HOMEBREW_PREFIX="$HOME/usr/local"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenter said you *can* use `$HOME` (or `~/`) But the script says to use the absolute path of your home directory.

Open up a terminal and type `echo $HOME` then put whatever it displays in place of `#{YOUR_HOME}`.

This way if it parses the string in any way it won't mess up.